# Не отправляются данные формы с помощью Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Нужно отправить данные с формы на почту. Как это правильно сделать?

Форма:

```
<form class="ajax_form" action="ajax_mail.php" method="get">
    <h2>Связаться с нами</h2>
    <label>
        <span>Ваше имя:</span>
        <input type="text" name="uname" required/>
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>Ваш телефон:</span>
        <input type="text" name="phone" required/>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="mail" required/>
    </label>
    <label>
        <span>Ваш город:</span>
        <select name="city">
            <option>Москва</option>
            <option>С-Петербург</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <div class="button_wrap">
        <button class="button btn_green" type="submit">Отправить заявку</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(".ajax_form").on('submit', function(e) {
    var formData = $(".ajax_form").serialize();
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "../mail_ajax.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: formData
    }).done(function() {
        alert("Спасибо за заявку!");
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
    header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    set_error_handler("var_dump");
    json_encode($_GET['uname']);
    $to = "user@gmail.com"; 
    $name = $_GET['uname'];  
    $phone = $_GET['phone'];
    $city = $_GET['city'];
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $subject = "Name:" . $name  . " , City:" . $city . " , Phone:" . $phone;
    $message = "message";
    $headers = "From:" . $email;
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: Исправил. Теперь почему-то при клике вообще ничего не происходит. На почту ничего не приходит.

Comment: А до этого приходили данные как из пустой формы? И ошибок никаких в консоли нет?

Comment: Данные, которые приходили: "Name: , City:Москва , Phone: ".  Город приходит. Ошибок в консоли нет.

Comment: Стоит посмотреть в каком виде вообще приходит информация на сервер.

Comment: Судя по [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t4ckbeLa/), данные из формы уходят нормально.

Comment: Как посмотреть в каком виде приходит информация на сервер?

Comment: В интернете пишут, что "чистый" запрос в PHP уже не получить: Apache сам разбирает запрос, и до PHP в первозданном виде запрос не доходит. Хотя бы убедитесь, что у вас из браузера запрос уходит в корректном виде, а на сервере просмотрите всё содержимое `$_GET`. И PHP-скрипт не валится с ошибкой? Мне, например, не нравится `json_encode($_GET['uname']);`: уж если кодировать, то `$name`. Негоже пытаться менять `$_GET` (это вообще законно в PHP?).

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснения, все работает, мне кажется причина была в том, что var formData = $(".ajax_form").serialize(); не внутри функции аякса как вы и говорили сначала. Потом я увидел, что в спам приходили письма.

Comment: На здоровье. В таком случае либо можете удалить вопрос, либо я могу разместить решение с `$(".ajax_form").serialize();` в качестве ответа, если вы готовы его принять.